# Turn two columns into one SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to turn this result:

```
Data1   Data2 
  A       C
  A       C
  A       D
  B       F
```

Into this one:

```
Data
A
B
C
D
F
```

Is there a way of doing this in SQL without using `UNION`, because the query to get this results is really long and I don't want to call it twice.
Thanks

Comment: why can't you use Union?

Comment: What version of Oracle? You could consider using UNPIVOT if you really don't want to use UNION.

Comment: @dancundy I can but I have a very long subquery that I don't wan't to repeat

Comment: @bluefeet I will take a look to unpivot then, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> the consult to get this results is really long and I don't want to call it twice.

I assume this means you have a complicated or expensive query you don't want to duplicate. You can use subquery factoring, also known as a common table expression or CTE, to treat your existing query as if it was a table:

```
with cte as (
  -- your existing query goes here
)
select data1 as data from cte
union
select data2 from cte
order by data
```